# Models extracted from gamre (LOL) get "mirrored"?

Tags: objects

I just downloaded Ahri models which was extracted from League, then I used the tool called "lol2dae" to convert the original model file (.skn) to .dae  file so I'm able to importing to Blender.

The model looks fine, I applied its texture (I used PS to convert it from dds to png), and nothing seem to be wrong.

Then I realized that the model has been "mirrored" from the original model.
I don't know if I used the word "mirrored" right.. just take a look at my screenshot here for sure.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also tried extracting some models myself and got the same problem, so I very appreciate any suggestion to make it work right.

Comment: Object/Mirror or Mesh/Mirror then select the axis to mirror on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply scale the object. In this tab, go down to "Scale:" and set the X value to negative.

[image: Scale Object - Set X Value to Negative]

Comment: Note that this inverts the normals under the hood so object scaled as above will look probably transparent when exported because engines often skip faces with normals pointing inside (and there might be other problems with modifiers, particulalry armature). Either apply scale and flip normals afterwards in Edit mode or use another method

Comment: Thanks for the help, also I'm new to blender so Mr Zak note is kinda tricky to me understand it, but I very appreciate and would keep it mind.